# Event End Datetime does not get set

Tags: apex, datetime, event

For a certain business use case, I need to set the End datetime of an Event to 25 seconds from its Start datetime. Through the below apex code, I have noticed that the system does not actually set the End datetime unless it is at least a minute from the Start datetime. Anyone know a way to do so?

```
Datetime startTime = datetime.Now();
Datetime endTime = startTime.addSeconds(25);

system.debug('------- local apex variables ------');
system.debug(startTime);
system.debug(endTime);

Event rec = new Event(
Subject = 'Test event',
StartDateTime = startTime,
EndDateTime = endTime);
insert rec;

rec = [SELECT StartDateTime, EndDateTime, DurationInMinutes FROM Event WHERE Id =:rec.Id];

system.debug('------- values on the record ------');
system.debug(Rec.StartDateTime);
system.debug(Rec.EndDateTime);
```

The debug log showed the following entries

```
09:40:40.9 (9235598)|EXECUTION_STARTED
09:40:40.9 (9239769)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
09:40:40.9 (9722311)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|------- local apex variables ------
09:40:40.9 (9741026)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|2017-09-13 16:40:40
09:40:40.9 (9747653)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|2017-09-13 16:41:05
09:40:40.9 (42598303)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|------- values on the record ------
09:40:40.9 (42637322)|USER_DEBUG|[17]|DEBUG|2017-09-13 16:40:40
09:40:40.9 (42657167)|USER_DEBUG|[18]|DEBUG|2017-09-13 16:40:40
09:40:40.9 (44089534)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
09:40:40.9 (44827761)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

As you can see the End datetime on the Event record is 2017-09-13 16:40:40 and not 2017-09-13 16:41:05. Any way, I can ensure the End datetime can be accurately updated?

Comment: I think the duration has to be at least one minute...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it has to be at least a minute. EndDateTime is tied to DurationInMinutes, which is defined as having no decimal component (it's a `Number(8,0)`). For example, an event can't be 3 minutes and 2 seconds long. You'll need to come up with some other solution that doesn't involve 25 second long events.